# Query json http response from browser

Tags: python, django, json, query-string

I have a view written in Django which returns JSON response like:

```
[{"pk": 3222, "model": "test.test", "fields": {"f1:f1, f3:f2"}}......etc]
```

The URL that returns this view is: `127.0.0.1:8000/someview/modelname/all`

However when I hit this on a browser `127.0.0.1:8000/someview/modelname/all?pk=3222`

I do not get the filtered result. How do I achieve this? Or is my understanding of query in a URL wrong.

**UPDATE:**

In my view:

```
obj = SomeModel.objects.all()
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', [obj,]))
```

Comment: If you don't provide underlying code how can we know what's going on?

Comment: Can you provide us with the code for your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're not doing any filtering in your code at all. Your first line says "give me all the SomeModel objects" and your second line says "here's an HTTP response of all the SomeModel objects as JSON."

Assuming you're not using class-based views, you can do something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def SomeView(request):
    obj = SomeModel.objects.all()
    if request.GET.get('pk') is not None:
        obj = get_object_or_404(SomeModel, pk=request.GET.get('pk'))
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', obj), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1):

You only must `GET` the `pk` argument and with the `pk`  you can `GET` the record:

```
if request.GET['pk']:
   p_k = int(request.GET['pk'])
   obj = Somemodel.objects.get(pk=p_k)
else:
   obj = SomeModel.objects.all()
```